# For loop refusing to step through

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have extreamly simple for loop, or so I thought, which is refusing to step through. Whenever I run th main code, this is an exsert, the code would just seem to not be running, I have narrowed it down to this For Loop.

```
Sub Test_3()

Dim b As Double
Dim a As Long
Dim xvalues As Double
Dim yvales As Double

b = 1

For a = 55 To 15 Step -0.25

    xvalues = a

    yvalues = (-0.000005023488366 * ((xvalues) ^ 6)) + (0.000988717992 * ((xvalues) ^ 5)) - (0.07843393602 * ((xvalues) ^ 4)) + (3.20338362 * ((xvalues) ^ 3)) - (70.82720195 * ((xvalues) ^ 2)) + (807.4320705 * xvalues) - 3512.053837

    Cells(1 + b, 12) = yvalues

    b = b + 1

Next a

End Sub
```

When I add breakpoints to each line, I find that after `For a = 55 to 15 Step -0.25` the code seems to end. I have no idea why that is. If i hold down F5 the breakpoint markers keeps jumping between `b = 1` and `For a = 55 To 15 Step -0.25` line

Any help would be appricated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `a` as a floating point value.
E.g. `Dim a as Double`

Currently it is a `Long` and `55 - 0.25` is always `55` in this case.

Take a look at this example, showing that `1+0.49` is `1`, when the counter is declared as a whole (integer) value:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim a As Long
    For a = 1 To 3 Step 0.49 'change to 0.5 to see difference
        Debug.Print a
        Stop                 'if you remove the Stop, you would go to infinite loop
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes thank you, as `Long` only defines whole numbers? Am i correct in that?

Comment: Yes, `Long` is for whole numbers, @CptGoodar

Comment: Excellent, which is why i assume it failed.